# Restart fragment after back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have several fragments that share the same container: Fragment A, Fragment B, Fragment C. I move through them with the .replace method and I always use .addToBackStack to keep them in the stack.

At the current moment, if Fragment C is displayed and I click the Back Button to go back to Fragment B the methods from onCreateView() of Fragment B onwards will be called, but not onAttach or onCreate. I would like to restart Fragment B completely after I click the Back Button so that these methods are also called. In other words, as if I had gone from Fragment B to a different Activity and then back to Fragment B.

Comment: What code would you need to run on the onCreate that can’t be ran on onCreateView? The only two ways I could think of are have a Boolean set on onCreate to mark as needs to restart next onCreateView (that’s a lot of extra work that’s going to be thrown away) or overwrite the onBackPressed method and have a showFragment1(), showFragment2() method that will create new ones to replace your currently displayed fragment

Comment: This is my problem @Brandon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050062/how-to-fix-view-that-is-misplaced-and-only-comes-to-right-place-after-i-scroll-i  ...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688364/how-to-avoid-admob-adview-being-cut-off .   I've already asked twice with no success